# How to update QDataWidgetMapper items without focus

Tags: c++, qt

I have several QLineEdits, each connecting to a single QStandardItemModel via their own QDataWidgetMapper, so that they all reflect the same value.

This works great if the user inputs a value in one QLineEdit - when the QLineEdit loses focus, the model is updated and all the other QLineEdits show the same value.

However, I want to set the values in one QLineEdit via QLineEdit::setText, and this does not do anything to make the QLineEdit lose focus. I could manually call submit on the QDataWidgetMapper, but this requires setting up access to that mapper which I'd rather avoid if I can help it, as it is in another class.

Is there a way to set the text in the QLineEdit as if a user has entered it, for example, so that the QDataWidgetMapper will submit?

Answer (score 5):

This was easier than I thought. When I set the mapper up, I can connect the QLineEdit's textChanged signal to the submit slot of the mapper.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, but this solution only works one way. If I update the model, the mapped widgets do not update. I made a post about it on the Qt forum: https://forum.qt.io/topic/121498/two-way-binding-with-qdatawidgetmapper